# How to load local html in div from svg <a> click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am trying to load a new local html page within a specific div when I click on an object within svg.  Here is the code I have.

```
<html>

<head>
<script> 
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("1.html");
});

</script>


<svg width="100%" height="95%">
      <a xlink:href="#" id="button" class="button">
    <text x="150" y="45" fill="red">My Div</text>
  </a>

    </svg>

<style type="text/css"> 
#div1 {
    position:absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 15%;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    margin-top: -9px; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
    margin-left: -15px; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    background-color: none;
}

</style>


<div id="div1">Div Placement</div>



</body>
</html>
```

I've fiddled with this for a few days with no avail.  I do not want to use the div hide/show method if at all possible.

Many thanks!

~ Leo

**EDIT**

okie I've tried doing what you did on the fiddle but it still will not change the div.

here is what I have now. Yes an index exists within the pages folder.

```
<html>


 <head>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js.jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js">         </script>    
 <script> 
$("#button").click(function(){
$("#div1").text("Loading...");
$("#div1").load("/pages/");
});</script>    



 </head>

  <body bgcolor="#000000">

  <svg width="100%" height="95%">

   <a xlink:href="#" id="button" class="button">
   <text x="150" y="45" fill="red">My Div</text>
 </a>


   </svg>


     <div id="div1">Div Placement</div>
```

**EDIT**

Third iteration of code, still not working

```
<html>


<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Float Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script> 
    $("#button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").text("Loading...");
    $("#div1").load("/pages/");
});</script>    



</head>

<body bgcolor="#000000">

<svg width="100%" height="95%">


        <a xlink:href="#" id="button" class="button">
    <text x="150" y="45" fill="red">My Div</text>
  </a>


    </svg>




<div id="div1">Div Placement</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/sumzujre/

The main problem seems to be that you aren't including the jQuery library.  Add this line to your page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, make sure that "1.html" exists.  If the server returns an error (eg. 404), nothing will be inserted into your div.

**Update:**

You will need to make sure the elements exist before you try to add event handlers to them.  Either move your `<script>` block to the end of the file, or you can leave it at the top and surround it with `$.ready()`.

```
<script> 

$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#button").click(function(){
      $("#div1").text("Loading...");
      $("#div1").load("/pages/");
   });

});

</script>
```

Comment: okie, its getting closer.  I am having it load the text of loading but it immediately switches back to the original div text of Div Placement. I have verified that the html document its calling is named index.html and it is placed within the pages folder I have tried a few variants of the html file address but to no avail.

Comment: Okie, revision, it does load the page it directed at after the loading text is displayed but it immediately goes back to the original div text

Comment: Thats the code I already have in there.  It works at 90%  I would say.  When I click the link it does change the div, twice as it should, at first saying loading...  then it pops to the other page(which at this time is just a placeholder(html/body tags and a little text) then it switches back to the div1 text of div placement as if I had never clicked on the link.  I ripped the code down to bare bones(ie basically the jfiddle) and I still get the same issue.  let me try and make a jfiddle and see if it has the same issues as I am describing

Comment: I must be missing something small on here.  Here is the jfiddle and its the same issue.  I won't be normally referencing cnn im just using it at a placer for the fiddle

Comment: Got it!, Many thanks!  I had removed the # from the xlink withing the svg <a> attribute.  Adding it seems to anchor it to the div and not allow an instant cycling within the div.  I wonder if the rapid cycling could be used to some effect though for data migration.  I will post a working copy.  If I could upvote I would do so.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I always use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Like this

```
<div id="my-content"></div> 
<a id="button">Click to load</a> 
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#button').live('click',function(){
 $.ajax({ 
   method: 'POST', 
   url:'yourPage.html', 
   success:function(data){
      $('#my-content').html(data)
   } 
})}) 
</script>
```

Comment: Now that I got it working your method works as well and in some ways could seem more versatile and universally useful.  I am not sure though as I am not a computer sciences major.  Thank you for this answer as I think it may be very useful in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>


<head>

  <title>Float Test</title>


</head>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>   





<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">




<svg width="100%" height="95%">


        <a xlink:href="#" id="button" class="button">
    <text x="150" y="45" fill="red">My Div</text>
  </a>


    </svg>



<style type="text/css"> 
#div1 {
    position:absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 15%;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    margin-top: -9px; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
    margin-left: -15px; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    background-color: none;
}

</style>


<div id="div1">Text</div>
```

Working iteration of code.  I had removed the hashtag within

```
<a xlink:href="#" id="button" class="button">
```

in my working code.  Thank you for your patience with my lack of thoroughness

```
</body>
</html>
<script> 
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("1.html");
});

</script>
```